# Input a one hot encoded sample to an LSTM network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I'm (making an attempt at) writing a neural network in Keras and Python to take a random 100 characters from a 760k character technical pdf and predict the next 50 characters with an LSTM net.

I've so far written code to one-hot encode the text. There are 98 unique characters (there are a few greek letters and such), so I expect the one hot encoded text to look like this:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0 ... 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1 ... 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0 ... 0, 0, 0]
          .
          .
          .
[0, 0, 0, 0 ... 0, 1, 0]
```

That is what shows up with my print statements. If needed, I can put the code that does that here. Then, my program selects every set of 100 one hot encoded characters to add to list `x` and the succeeding 1 one hot encoded character to add to list `y`. This creates a 3d input list.

My trouble arises when porting that python list into a numpy list for my model. No matter how I attempt to reshape the list with `x = asarray(x).reshape`, I'll always get an error: `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size [LARGE NUMBER] into shape ([LARGE NUMBER],100,1)`. To me, this means that I do not have the correct x, y, and z values for the dimensions, which some multiplication proves. But I just cannot figure out what the correct values are. What are the correct values?

This seems like a basic question, but I know basically nothing regarding ML and especially LSTMs. So what's the hopefully small and simple thing I'm missing?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: you can use reshape(x,y,-1). The -1 here takes care of the calculation of the dimension on its own, you need only specify the x and y. If need be you can make any of the values -1 and the other two to be values you are sure to be

Comment: Can you provide the code? If you are trying to reshape A to B, number elements in A & B should be same.

Comment: @Illuminati0x5B Not necessarily a to b, unless some b is demanded by the LSTM layer.

Comment: @SuryaPalaniswamy Good suggestion, but now I can't figure out how to feed that data into the LSTM. Is there a type of input that the LSTM keras layer expects? I got an error relating to the categorical crossentropy loss algorithm.

Comment: I don't have much idea about LSTMs but here is what I found: the input needs to be of the form` [num_examples, num_timesteps, num_features]`